# (Z("onerror="alert`5986267575`")) section in between URL in ASP.NET Webforms rendering an alert

Tags: asp.net, xss

[image: Example URL that triggers an alert]
I am developing an ASP.NET 4.5 application, during testing i realised having alert in between a url lets browser to render alert. i have added ValidateRequest="true" at global level to reject any XSS .

Can you help me with this.

Comment: What is that parameter in your routing? How is it ending up echoed to the page as script? I've never seen anything like that before, so you probably have something that's doing that deliberately?

Comment: Hi , Actually i am not using any kind of routing rather navigation to web pages using their relative path of file e.g <a runat="server" href="~/UserAdministration.aspx">

Comment: I meant [routing like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing) on the server side to process URLs. You probably have something there, or maybe as an HTTP Filter, that's extracting the `(Z(...))` parameter from your URL and doing something with it? I would be surprised if this was something built into ASP.NET doing this: it seems much more likely to me that it's your own code, or possibly some extra framework that you're using.